# Pass in variable from shell script to applescript

Tags: bash, shell, applescript, osascript

I've got a shell script that I call that uses `osascript`, and that `osascript` calls a shell script and passes in a variable that I've set in the original shell script.  I don't know how to pass that variable in from the applescript to shell script.

How can I pass in a variable from shell script to applescript to shell script...?

Let me know if I don't make sense.

```
 i=0
 for line in $(system_profiler SPUSBDataType | sed -n -e '/iPad/,/Serial/p' -e '/iPhone/,/Serial/p' | grep "Serial Number:" | awk -F ": " '{print $2}'); do
 UDID=${line}
 echo $UDID
 #i=$(($i+1))
 sleep 1


 osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' \
 -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down' \
 -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd '$current_dir'" in selected tab of the front window' \
 -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "./script.sh ip_address '${#UDID}' &" in selected tab of the front window'

 done
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Shell variables don't expand inside single quotes. When you to want pass a shell variable to `osascript` you need to use double `""` quotes. The problem is, than you must escape double quotes needed inside the osascript, like:

the script

```
say "Hello" using "Alex"
```

you need escape quotes

```
text="Hello"
osascript -e "say \"$text\" using \"Alex\""
```

This not very readable, therefore it much better to use the bash's `heredoc` feature, like

```
text="Hello world"
osascript <<EOF
say "$text" using "Alex"
EOF
```

And you can write multiline script inside for a free, it is much better than using multiple `-e` args...

Comment: This is bad advice. Aside from being unnecessarily clumsy, it does not sanitize the inserted text so is neither robust nor secure, e.g. `text='Bob says "hello"'` will cause AS to throw a syntax error due to unescaped quotes. Never use code munging if a better solution exists, which it does: as Lauri Ranta said, define an explicit `run` handler and pass your strings via ARGV. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966117/bash-combining-variables-to-form-a-command-sent-to-applescript-using-the-osascr/16977401#16977401 for more detail.

Comment: @foo You're right, using `on run argv` is "more" correct. Mine is not an _perfect_ solution, but i'm used it myself many-many times without any problems, it is simple and usable for many scripts...

Comment: Yours is a _buggy_ solution. If $text contains double quote or backslash characters it will cause the AS code either to error or - worse - behave in unintended ways. If you must use code munging, you _must_ sanitize your inputs. e.g. Google "SQL injection attack" to understand why "it works for me" is _not_ an appropriate response when someone points out this flaw.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a run handler or export:

```
osascript -e 'on run argv
    item 1 of argv
end run' aa

osascript -e 'on run argv
    item 1 of argv
end run' -- -aa

osascript - -aa <<'END' 2> /dev/null
on run {a}
    a
end run
END

export v=1
osascript -e 'system attribute "v"'
```

I don't know any way to get STDIN. `on run {input, arguments}` only works in Automator.

Answer (score 0):

Below is what worked for me.

`pathToRepo` is the variable, which `osascript` passed to a Terminal that was open and it `cd` into the correct directory. (And then run `npm start` which is just for reference if you wanted to add more commands)

```
pathToRepo="/Users/<YOUR_MAC_NAME>/Documents/<REPO_NAME>"

osascript - "$pathToRepo" <<EOF
    on run argv -- argv is a list of strings
        tell application "Terminal"
            do script ("cd " & quoted form of item 1 of argv & " && npm start")
        end tell
    end run
EOF
```

Source/Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67413043/6217734