# how to pass bash variables to AppleScript

Tags: bash, variables, applescript, imessage

```
#/bin/bash
corr="apple"
echo $corr

osascript -e 'tell application "Messages" to send  "Did you mean "'"$corr"'" "  to buddy  "A"'
```

Error:

```
51:57: syntax error: A identifier can’t go after this “"”. (-2740)
```

If I just pass

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Messages" to send  "Did you mean $corr "  to buddy  "A"'
```

the message comes like "Did you mean $corr"

I have tried everything mentioned at [Pass in variable from shell script to applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242773/pass-in-variable-from-shell-script-to-applescript)

Comment: formatting was horrendous. should be more readable now

Comment: If you are trying to send the literal string `Did you mean "apple"`, then you aren't escaping the quotation marks around `apple`. The first one closes the message, so that `apple` is an unexpected identifier, not part of the message string.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good explanation with decent examples at the very end of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966117/combining-variables-in-bash-to-form-a-command-sent-to-applescript-using-the-osas/16977401#16977401).

Based on that, I was able to make this work (using TextEdit, not Messages):

```
 #!/bin/sh
rightNow=$(date +"%m_%d%B%Y")
osascript -e 'on run {rightNow}' -e 'tell application "TextEdit" to make new document with properties{name: "Date003.txt", text:rightNow}'  -e 'end run' $rightNow
```

I also found that I had to be VERY careful about the single and double quotes.  For some reason, my keyboard kept replacing the plain quotes with curled quotes.  Annoying.

Comment: One can disable that option (replacing quotes) in TextEdit's preferences

Comment: @Zero Thank you!  I rarely use TextEdit for shell scripts, but I thought this would be simple.  Now it is fixed.

Comment: While not essential in this particular example, I would also strongly recommend double-quoting `$rightNow` at the end. It's a _very_ good habit to get into when writing bash scripts as it ensures correct behavior should the string being inserted contain any spaces. (Bash is such a POS it can't even do variable substitution right - instead it just inserts the raw string as-is and parses it as code. e.g. If the string is `foo bar` then `$rightNow` will be replaced by _two_ separate arguments, `foo` and `bar`, unless you explicitly wrap the variable name in quotes: `"$rightNow"` → `"foo bar"`.)