# osascript how to pass in a variable

Tags: bash, applescript

I have the following, not working. It opens up a new tab in Terminal but the variable $DomainName is not passed in?

```
DomainName="example.com"
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "watch dig +short NS $DomainName"'
```

Outcome is:

```
watch dig +short NS $DomainName
```

How do you pass in a variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OP’s question is a masterclass in how [not to] sanitize shell script inputs when calling `osascript`.

This is dangerously unsafe:

```
foo="DO NOT DO THIS; say bad script"
osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"echo $foo\""
```

(Run that example to see what I mean, then consider what a less friendly string could wreak.)

Double-quoting the variable `$foo` as `"$foo"` gets it safely through the top-level shell script. It does **NOT** get it safely through the AppleScript:

```
foo="say \"bad script\""
osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"echo $foo\""
```

If you run that example, it will fail with an AppleScript compilation error: A identifier can’t go after this “"”. (-2740)

That’s because `osascript` receives the string:

```
tell application "Terminal" to do script "echo say "bad script""
```

which is invalid syntax. (Try compiling that line in Script Editor to see.)

The correct way to pass AppleScript arguments is by appending them to `osascript`’s arguments list:

```
osascript -ss -e "…" - "arg1" "arg2" "arg3"
```

The `-` separator is required to separate the command’s own options list from the remaining arguments to be forwarded to the AppleScript’s `run` handler.

BTW, is also a good idea to pass the AppleScript via `osascript`’s stdin instead of `-e` options, as that lets you write normal AppleScript code without having to escape it as well:

```
osascript -ss - "arg1" "arg2" "arg3" <<EOF

    on run argv -- argv is a list of 3 strings
        argv -- do stuff with argv here
    end run

EOF
```

(You can run that example safely: it just writes the value of `argv` to stdout.)

Okay, so that’s safe as far as passing arguments into AppleScript goes.

..

*However*, OP’s AppleScript creates a new shell script to be run in Terminal.app. Therefore, it is *also* essential to sanitize the AppleScript strings used to construct that shell script, which is done using AppleScript’s `quoted form of STRING` property.

So here is the correct *safe* way to sanitize arbitrary strings through all *three* levels of code generation:

```
bar='$test" \t#est*;say bad script' # a proper nasty test string

osascript -  "$bar"  <<EOF

    on run argv -- argv is a list of strings
        tell application "Terminal"
            do script ("echo " & quoted form of item 1 of argv)
        end tell
    end run

EOF
```

Run that example, and the fairly horrible test string I’ve used here is passed safely all the way to `echo`.

And yes, all this string sanitization/code generation stuff *is* a headache, but that’s what you get for using so many languages designed by crazy people.

Answer (score 0):

for me, that was the simplest and easiest:

save the following as `test.sh` and `chmod +x test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

action=$1

osascript <<EOF

if "$action" is "off" then
   tell application "Terminal"
        do script ("echo  it is now off")
   end tell
end if
EOF
```

now you can run the script with `test.sh` vs. `test.sh off` and see how in the case of "off" parameter is causing the terminal to be opened.