# Run 2 commands in applescript/osascript with variable

Tags: bash, shell, applescript, sh, osascript

I am trying to run 2 commands stored in a variable with `osascript`

This is my `start.sh`

```sh
currentDirectory="cd $(pwd) && npm run start"

echo $currentDirectory

osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script '"${currentDirectory}"''
```

I am getting this as the output

```
sh start.sh
cd /Users/Picadillo/Movies/my-test-tepo && npm run start
83:84: syntax error: Expected expression but found “&”. (-2741)
```

Comment: I suggest to remove `cd $(pwd) &&` from your code.

Comment: @Cyrus I need that, I am starting that script from an MFE that needs other repo running

Comment: It doesn't do anything. `$(pwd)` is the current directory, it's changing to where it already is.

Comment: @Barmar Try running `cd Documents && osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "ls"'` and you will see the `ls` output from the `~` directory

Comment: Oh, I see. `$(pwd)` is being expanded in the context of the oroginal shell script, it's needed to get the AppleScript into the same directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Barmar: The argument to do script needs to be in double quotes.

Yes; however, the way you’ve done it is still unsafe.

If the path itself contains backslashes or double quotes, AS will throw a syntax error as the munged AS code string fails to compile. (One might even construct a malicious file path to execute arbitrary AS.) While these are not characters that frequently appear in file paths, best safe than sorry. Quoting string literals correctly is always a nightmare; correctly quoting them all the way through shell *and* AppleScript quadratically so.

Fortunately, there is an easy way to do it:

```
currentDirectory="$(pwd)"

osascript - "${currentDirectory}" <<EOF 
on run {currentDirectory}
  tell application "Terminal"
    do script "cd " & (quoted form of currentDirectory) & " && npm run start"
  end tell
end run
EOF
```

Pass the `currentDirectory` path as an additional *argument* to `osascript` (the `-` separates any options flags from extra args) and `osascript` will pass the extra argument strings as parameters to the AppleScript’s `run handler`. To single-quote that AppleScript string to pass back to shell, simply get its `quoted form` property.

Bonus: scripts written this way are cleaner and easier to read too, so less chance of overlooking any quoting bugs you have in your shell code.

Comment: +⒈  This is the correct answer for anyone undecided, in case @LuisEnMarroquin doesn't return to update his choice.

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `do script` needs to be in double quotes.

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "'"${currentDirectory}"'"'
```

You should also put the argument to `cd` in quotes, in case it contains spaces.

```
currentDirectory="cd '$(pwd)' && npm run start"
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is what worked for me.

`pathToRepo` is the variable, which `osascript` passed to a Terminal that was open and it `cd` into the correct directory. (And then run `npm start` which is just for reference if you wanted to add more commands)

```
pathToRepo="/Users/<YOUR_MAC_NAME>/Documents/<REPO_NAME>"

osascript - "$pathToRepo" <<EOF
    on run argv -- argv is a list of strings
        tell application "Terminal"
            do script ("cd " & quoted form of item 1 of argv & " && npm start")
        end tell
    end run
EOF
```

Source/Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67413043/6217734