# How to deal with white spaces in osascript

Tags: bash, syntax, applescript, osascript

I'm in need of your assistance on how to deal with white space in a path.

In my example below, I'm setting some variables in a Terminal bash shell and executing, "osascript" from command line, utilizing these variables to run ['do shell script'] & ['display dialog']. When I run these from command line, I'm getting different results. My ultimate goal here is to be able to execute ['do shell script'] and it execute the bash shell script based on the path. In this case, the path has spaces in it.

NOTE: The `INSTALLER_PATH` variable defined below is set like this because the path is generated from an Apple Script I wrote that basically takes a path [ with white spaces in it ] and combines that path with another variable. Because this path has spaces in the name, I'm using the [ to quoted form of ] setting that puts the path in quotes.

APPLE SCRIPT EXAMPLE:

---

```
set pathToApp to POSIX path of ((path to me) as text)
set dragonFrame to ("_DRAGONFRAME/")
set INSTALLER_PATH to quoted form of pathToApp & dragonFrame
display dialog INSTALLER_PATH
```

---

GENERATES THIS PATH {notice the ticks}:

```
'/Volumes/Free.Space/Shotgun Python Dragon Project 2017/DRAGONFRAME_SCRIPTS_MASTER_V1.02/Dragonframe_Scripts_Installer.app/'_DRAGONFRAME/
```

---

Instead of testing this through the Apple Script to find the exact syntax I would need, I figured it would be easier to test this from command line. This is exactly what I'm setting and executing from my Terminal command line. In the examples below, executing [ 'display dialog' ] works and [ 'do shell script' ] fails. I think if there's a way to enclose the entire path in double quotation marks, my problem would be solved although all attempts at getting the path enclosed in double quotation marks has failed:

```
%> INSTALLER_PATH='/Volumes/Free.Space/Shotgun Python Dragon Project 2017/DRAGONFRAME_SCRIPTS_MASTER_V1.02/Dragonframe_Scripts_Installer.app/'_DRAGONFRAME/ 

%> ADMIN_USER_PROC="_Python_PySide_QT_Installer/Scripts/AdminUserProcesses.sh"

%> osascript -e 'do shell script ("'"${INSTALLER_PATH}"'" & "'"${ADMIN_USER_PROC}"'")'
```

---

GENERATES THIS ERROR:

```
0:217: execution error: sh: /Volumes/Free.Space/Shotgun: No such file or directory (127)
```

---

```
%> osascript -e 'display dialog ("'"${INSTALLER_PATH}"'" & "'"${ADMIN_USER_PROC}"'")'
```

---

GENERATES THIS PATH:

```
/Volumes/Free.Space/Shotgun Python Dragon Project 2017/DRAGONFRAME_SCRIPTS_MASTER_V1.02/Dragonframe_Scripts_Installer.app/_DRAGONFRAME/_Python_PySide_QT_Installer/Scripts/AdminUserProcesses.sh
```

---

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: [How to pass values into an AppleScript as `run` handler parameters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966117/combining-variables-in-bash-to-form-a-command-sent-to-applescript-using-the-osas/16977401#16977401)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something similar to this syntax:

```
set dragonFrame to ("/_DRAGONFRAME/")
set INSTALLER_PATH to path of (pathToApp & dragonFrame)
```

**Result**:

```
'/Volumes/Free.Space/Shotgun Python Dragon Project 2017/DRAGONFRAME_SCRIPTS_MASTER_V1.02/Dragonframe_Scripts_Installer.app/_DRAGONFRAME/'
```

If you need double-quotes around the path you can use:

```
("\"" & pathToApp & dragonFrame & "\"")
```

and get rid of the quoted form argument leaving you with:

```
set INSTALLER_PATH to ("\"" & pathToApp & dragonFrame & "\"")
```